# Is it the good way to post variable with ajax processing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to `post` a pseudo with `ajax` like in the title , i think actually with my code i send no informations to my `php` file.

so this is the code :

```js
$('#send').click(function(){
     var pseudo = $('#psd').val();
});

function recuppoint() {
    $.post('point.php',{pseudo: pseudo} ,function(data) {
         console.log('['+data + ']');
         $('.infos2').html(data);
    });
}
setInterval(recuppoint, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="logForm" action="">
    <div class="field">
     <label class="field-label" for="mailconnect">Votre mail</label>
     <input class="field-input"type="email" name="mailconnect" id="email" />  
    </div> 
    <div class="field" id="psd">
     <label class="field-label" for="client">pseudo client</label>
     <input class="field-input" type="text" name="pseudo" id="pseudo" />
    </div>   
    <div class="field">
     <label class="field-label" for="mdpconnect">mdp</label>
     <input class="field-input" type="password" name="mdpconnect" id="password" /> 
    </div> 
    <button   id="send" class="send"name="formsubscribe">begin</button>
</form>
        
<div>
    <div id="infos" class="infos" align="center"> </div>
    <div id="infos2" class="infos2" align="center"> </div>  
</div>
```

So guys how can i solve the problem with the var pseudo ?

thank you

Comment: `pseudo` is not a global variable. declare it outside the click function so the `recuppoint` can access it

Comment: Wow, so every second its sending this ajax request... and only if they click a button, it will (well, when this code is fixed) send the value with it. That seems like a deathly open wound to introduce, no?

Comment: yea you right dude i ll put with the form the pseudo in db, then i declare in my script var pseudo =<?php .db request.. ?>

Answer (score 1):

Your div element with id "psd", doesnt have value. If you want to send html use .html(); If you want to get only input values so try some like this:

```
var x = $('input[name=nameOfInput]').val();
```

Then you should send it with ajax.

Answer (score 1):

your `ajax` call should be like this .

you can not access the `input` field with its parent id as you did  `$('#psd').val();`
but you can access it value with its id itself like this

```
<input class="field-input" type="text" name="pseudo" id="pseudo" />
```

```js
$('#send').on('click', function(){
     var pseudo = $('#pseudo').val();
     $.ajax({
          url:'point.php',
          type:'POST',
          data:{ ele: pseudo},
          success:function(data){
              $('.infos2').html(data);
          } 
      }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="logForm" action="">
    <div class="field">
     <label class="field-label" for="mailconnect">Votre mail</label>
     <input class="field-input"type="email" name="mailconnect" id="email" />  
    </div> 
    <div class="field" id="psd">
     <label class="field-label" for="client">pseudo client</label>
     <input class="field-input" type="text" name="pseudo" id="pseudo" />
    </div>   
    <div class="field">
     <label class="field-label" for="mdpconnect">mdp</label>
     <input class="field-input" type="password" name="mdpconnect" id="password" /> 
    </div> 
    <button   id="send" class="send"name="formsubscribe">begin</button>
</form>
        
<div>
    <div id="infos" class="infos" align="center"> </div>
    <div id="infos2" class="infos2" align="center"> </div>  
</div>
```